# Debug bench function in bench target rise "Multiple compilation artifacts are not supported." error

Tags: rust, benchmarking, rust-analyzer

env: Use VScode + RA with nightly Rust toolchain.

e.g. bench.rs file

```
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;
use test::*;

#[bench]
fn demo(b:& Bencher){
       ...

}
```

When click `Debug` lens trigger "Multiple compilation artifacts are not supported" error, but click `Run Bench` works normally.

Ironically, if you put the `demo` fn in other `bin lib test example` target everything works fine. Why debug bench fn in `bench` target occur problems?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in rust-analyzer. See [issue #12645](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/12645).

I sent a PR to fix it: [#12655](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/pull/12655).